# Error message - kexts installed improperly

Tags: macos, kernel, kext

I have just gotten an error message for **every single kext** file there is.
The error message goes something along the lines of:

> The system extension "*file path*" was installed improperly and cannot be used. please try reinstalling it, or contact the products vendor for an update.

If there is something I could do to fix it, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, reinstall mac os :)

Comment: Did you give up and resort to this, or did you find a semi-official support statement somewhere?

Comment: @Eroen: i couldn't fix it so i gave up and did this instead